# Importing a module that requires other packages

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to learn to use modules to clean up my code. I'm running into problems with scope. I understand that when you import a module, Python gives that module a separate scope. I'm sure an answer to this is in the docs somewhere but I can't seem to find it.

I create a module `info.py` which includes a function `getStuff`:

```
def getStuff(key):
    db_info = 'db_location' + 'db_credentials'
    db = create_engine('postgresql://' + db_info)
    connection = db.connect()
    data = do_sql_stuff(SELECT things FROM stuff)
    return(data)
```

Then in the Python interpreter, I input

```
>>>> import sqlalchemy
>>>> import info
>>>> data = getStuff(key)
```

and get the error message

```
NameError: name 'create_engine' is not defined
```

This tells me that `info.py` doesn't have access to SQLAlchemy. If I were to define `getStuff` in the interpreter, it runs correctly.

How do I set up a module so that it can access other packages?

Answer (score 0):

As I was expecting, there is a pretty simple solution to this problem. All that one needs to do is put the `import` statements at the top of the `info.py` file.