# Can a module see a package already imported?

Tags: python, pandas, module

I process data from different sources, and often I have that data downloaded as a spreadsheet.  I want to have processing modules defined for each of the data sources - they will load the data, rename columns, etc. A "prep" module would load shared packages and variables, and then load the processing modules.  However, the processing modules do not have access to the packages and variables in the "prep" module.

#### Toy Example

`prep.py`

```
# Load shared packages and variables.    
import pandas as pd
keyFolder = '/Keys/'
    
# Import processing modules
from process import processData
```

`process.py`

```
processData(filename):
    data = pd.read_excel(filename)  # References pd
    key = pd.read_excel(keyFolder+'dataKey.xlsx', index_col = 'oldName').newName # References keyFolder
    data = data.rename(columns=key)
```

Result:

> **NameError:** name 'pd' is not defined

A similar problem happens with the variable `keyFolder` if I get past `pd`.

One solution is to load pandas directly into each "process" module, as per
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621063/importing-a-module-that-requires-other-packages).  But I want to have several processing modules - they are actually fairly long and involved, and better kept separate.  Reloading pandas multiple times seems inefficient.

Is there a better approach?